# Error ReflectionException Class App\Http\Controllers\Agente does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Good Morning!

What are the possible errors in this case?

being in the routes file this way,

Route::resource('/cadastro', 'AgentesController');

Comment: What is the name of the model you want to control?

Comment: the model name is Agentes

Comment: Trying recreating the resource controller with the hinting model name option like that: `php artisan make:controller AgentesController --resource --model=Agentes`, you can read more here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers